# How to make text to grow vertically AND truncate?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

My code is as simple as:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Container(
              height: 60,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ));
  }
}
```

It produces the following:

[image]

What I want to achieve is:

[image]

I was able to do so by adding `maxLines: 3` to `Text`, but obviously hard-coding `maxLines` is not an options.

I want `Text` to fill the entire height of the parent element and truncate with ellipsis if needed.

Comment: @Eugene height can vary based on aspect ratio and screen width. Calculating `maxLines` is not as trivial as calculating height knowing aspect ratio and width.

Comment: I hardcoded height just to illustrate the problem here

Answer (score 1):

what about this

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
          height: 60,
          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (context, constraints) {
                    return Text(
                      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      maxLines: (constraints.maxHeight / Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.fontSize).floor() - 1,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this looks like a workaround rather than a real solution. I'd only use that if there's no other option